# "Cannot access database on the main thread" error when trying to get paging source from room inside paging 3 pager

Tags: android-room, android-paging-3

> E/ROOM: Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:385)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:441)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:429)
> at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$1.checkUpdatedTable(InvalidationTracker.java:461)
> at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run(InvalidationTracker.java:431)
> at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker.refreshVersionsSync(InvalidationTracker.java:513)
> at androidx.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource.isInvalid(LimitOffsetDataSource.java:101)
> at androidx.paging.LegacyPagingSource.(LegacyPagingSource.kt:50)
> at androidx.paging.DataSource$Factory$asPagingSourceFactory$1.invoke(DataSource.kt:238)
> at androidx.paging.DataSource$Factory$asPagingSourceFactory$1.invoke(DataSource.kt:138)
> at androidx.paging.SuspendingPagingSourceFactory.invoke(SuspendingPagingSourceFactory.kt:41)
> at androidx.paging.SuspendingPagingSourceFactory.invoke(SuspendingPagingSourceFactory.kt:30)
> at my.lobbi.data.local.dao.MessageDao_Impl.getChatMessages(MessageDao_Impl.java:2005)

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: issuetracker.google.com/issues/175139766

Comment: thanks @Lewis, im using alpha13 version, meaning it will be fixed soon?

Comment: fixed in the latest paging release.

Comment: @Lewis just updated this evening, thanks a lot!